# $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$ and the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on  $(a,b)$ three times, and there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$.

Prove that for all $x \in (a,b)$ there exists $m \in  (a,b)$ such that 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{6}(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)f'''(m)$$

$f'''$ is the third derivative of the function $f$

Stuck. I can prove that there is an $m$ such that $f''(m)=0$ but that's it.
I don't think we're gonna use the antiderivative of the function either, I have no idea how they came up with the $1/6$.

This is not a homework question, I  was solving random questions and got stuck here.